# How do I get the information from a meta tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, meta-tags

The information I need is in a meta tag. How can I access the `"content"` data of the meta tag when `property="video"`?

**HTML:**

```
<meta property="video" content="http://video.com/video33353.mp4" />
```

Comment: Note that `<meta>` is supposed to have a `name` attribute, not `property`. Developers using the standard attribute will need to adapt the code given by most answers.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function getMeta(metaName) {
  const metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

  for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    if (metas[i].getAttribute('name') === metaName) {
      return metas[i].getAttribute('content');
    }
  }

  return '';
}

console.log(getMeta('video'));
```

Comment: What you really want is 'let' to keep them locally defined ;)

Comment: If you can use querySelector, you can do something like this:

`document.querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute('content')`

Comment: I think this answer is not more relevant and you should really use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript/35649085#35649085

Comment: Skip this answer. It doesn't work in the OP's [admittedly odd] case since it looks at the "name" rather than "property" attribute. And in its current state it's overly complex but without any backwards compatibility advantage — any browsers that support `const`/`let` should support `.querySelector`!

Comment: for just one meta attribute, why to loop over multiple times ? it may have hundreds of meta tags or it may need to get the meta value multiple times.

Comment: why would someone loop through all metas everytime ? if there are hundreds, what about the performance ?

Answer (score 372):

The other answers should probably do the trick, but this one is simpler and does not require jQuery:

```
document.head.querySelector("[property~=video][content]").content;
```

The original question used an [RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property) tag with a `property=""` attribute. For the normal HTML `<meta name="" …>` tags you could use something like:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content
```

Comment: Even though my meta is in the <head> tag, `document.head.querySelector` gave me `null` but `document.querySelector` worked perfectly

Comment: To get it working with OG tags add quotes to it like this_: var title = document.head.querySelector('[property="og:title"]');

Comment: NIce. Which purpose does the part "[content]" serve? Without it, I also get the meta element.

Comment: @citykid It does seem somewhat superfluous. The snippet will always throw a TypeError if the tag is not found by its "property". Including `[content]` in the selector extends that exception to the case where any matching tag lacks a content attribute. IMO it makes more sense in that case to get a null result but it's up to the implementer's preference I guess.

Comment: `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` does not work when unclosed element does not end with `/`, for example on this site, meta tag viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` is without `/` and `document.querySelector(meta[property='viewport'])`
returns null.

Answer (score 134):

One liner here

```
document.querySelector("meta[property='og:image']").getAttribute("content");
```

Answer (score 31):

There is an easier way:

```
document.getElementsByName('name of metatag')[0].getAttribute('content')
```

Comment: This works back to at least IE11, which makes it more useful.

Comment: The `document.querySelector` version works all the way to IE8, so it's plenty

Comment: This is a pretty good way normally, but note that the OP is using the RDFa "property" attribute instead of the more basic "name" attribute (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property)

Answer (score 21):

```
function getMetaContentByName(name,content){
   var content = (content==null)?'content':content;
   return document.querySelector("meta[name='"+name+"']").getAttribute(content);
}
```

Used in this way:

```
getMetaContentByName("video");
```

The example on this page:

```
getMetaContentByName("twitter:domain");
```

Comment: I used this tidbit, but on a certain page was getting a `type error` as `undefined` because the meta tag itself was missing.  I resolved that by assigning a variable and wrapping the `document.queryselector` in a try statement so I could get `""` by default in case of error.

Comment: function getMetaContentByName(name,content){
   var content = (content==null)?'content':content;
   try{
      return document.querySelector("meta[name='"+name+"']").getAttribute(content);
   }catch{
      return null;
   }
}

Answer (score 17):

If you use JQuery, you can use:

```
$("meta[property='video']").attr('content');
```

Comment: Assuming jquery, or some library; not javascript

Answer (score 16):

In Jquery you can achieve this with:

```
$("meta[property='video']");
```

In JavaScript you can achieve this with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta').item(property='video');
```

Comment: This seems to work (atleast in chrome) : `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['video'].getAttribute('content');` if the markup is as below: `<meta name="video" content="http://video.com/video33353.mp4" />`

Comment: @samdeV, this is the cleanest of all the solutions here. Submit it as your own answer.  :)

Comment: @samdeV, also you don't need to .getAttribute('content'), you can just .content: document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['video'].content. I just tested, this works fine in Firefox as well.

Comment: I am now informed that it doesn't work in Safari.  Damnit.

Answer (score 10):

```
document.querySelector('meta[property="video"]').content
```

this way you can get the content of the meta.

Answer (score 6):

**Way** - **[** 1 **]**

```
function getMetaContent(property, name){
    return document.head.querySelector("["+property+"="+name+"]").content;
}
console.log(getMetaContent('name', 'csrf-token'));
```

You may get error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

---

**Way** - **[** 2 **]**

```
function getMetaContent(name){
    return document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[name].getAttribute("content");
}
console.log(getMetaContent('csrf-token'));
```

You may get error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

---

**Way** - **[** 3 **]**

```
function getMetaContent(name){
    name = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[name];
    if(name != undefined){
        name = name.getAttribute("content");
        if(name != undefined){
            return name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
console.log(getMetaContent('csrf-token'));
```

Instead getting error, you get `null`, that is good.

Comment: its awsome , i need this code just for csrf-token

Answer (score 5):

Simple one, right?

```
document.head.querySelector("meta[property=video]").content
```

Answer (score 3):

My variant of the function:

```
const getMetaValue = (name) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(`meta[name="${name}"]`)
  return element?.getAttribute('content')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me

```
<meta name="text" property="text" content="This is text" />
<meta name="video" property="text" content="http://video.com/video33353.mp4" />
```

JS

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].name=="video")
        {
             alert(x[i].content);
         }

    }
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/muthupandiant/ogfLwdwt/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that will return the content of any meta tag and will memoize the result, avoiding unnecessary querying of the DOM.

```
var getMetaContent = (function(){
        var metas = {};
        var metaGetter = function(metaName){
            var theMetaContent, wasDOMQueried = true;;
            if (metas[metaName]) {
                theMetaContent = metas[metaName];
                wasDOMQueried = false;
            }
            else {
                 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("meta"), function(el) {
                    if (el.name === metaName) theMetaContent = el.content;
                    metas[metaName] = theMetaContent;
                });
            }
            console.log("Q:wasDOMQueried? A:" + wasDOMQueried);
            return theMetaContent;
        }
        return metaGetter;
    })();

getMetaContent("description"); /* getMetaContent console.logs the content of the description metatag. If invoked a second time it confirms that the DOM  was only queried once */
```

And here's an extended version that also queries for [open graph tags](http://ogp.me/), and uses [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var getMetaContent = (function(){
        var metas = {};
        var metaGetter = function(metaName){
            wasDOMQueried = true;
            if (metas[metaName]) {
                wasDOMQueried = false;
            }
            else {
                 Array.prototype.some.call(document.getElementsByTagName("meta"), function(el) {
                        if(el.name === metaName){
                           metas[metaName] = el.content;
                           return true;
                        }
                        if(el.getAttribute("property") === metaName){
                           metas[metaName] = el.content;
                           return true;
                        }
                        else{
                          metas[metaName] = "meta tag not found";
                        }  
                    });
            }
            console.info("Q:wasDOMQueried? A:" + wasDOMQueried);
            console.info(metas);
            return metas[metaName];
        }
        return metaGetter;
    })();

getMetaContent("video"); // "http://video.com/video33353.mp4"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDescription() {
    var info = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    return [].filter.call(info, function (val) {
        if(val.name === 'description') return val;
    })[0].content;
}
```

update version:

```
function getDesc() {
    var desc = document.head.querySelector('meta[name=description]');
    return desc ? desc.content : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

copy all meta values to a cache-object:

```js
/* <meta name="video" content="some-video"> */

const meta = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('meta[name]')).reduce((acc, meta) => (
  Object.assign(acc, { [meta.name]: meta.content })), {});

console.log(meta.video);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way preferred

We can use direct one line to get meta description or keyword or any meta tag in head section as this code:

```
document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta')['description'].getAttribute('content');
```

Just change ['description'] to keywords or element of meta name rang

This is an example:
[using document.head to get meta names values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnHQO.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interessted in a more far-reaching solution to get all meta tags you could use this piece of code

```
function getAllMetas() {
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    var summary = [];
    Array.from(metas)
        .forEach((meta) => {
            var tempsum = {};
            var attributes = meta.getAttributeNames();
            attributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                tempsum[attribute] = meta.getAttribute(attribute);
            });
            summary.push(tempsum);
        });
    return summary;
}

// usage
console.log(getAllMetas());
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to just get them in one object hash, then I can access them anywhere. This could easily be set to an injectable variable and then everything could have it and it only grabbed once.

By wrapping the function this can also be done as a one liner.

```
var meta = (function () {
    var m = document.querySelectorAll("meta"), r = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i += 1) {
        r[m[i].getAttribute("name")] = m[i].getAttribute("content")
    }
    return r;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta global attributes are valid which means the **`id` attribute can be used with `getElementById`**.

Answer (score 0):

Using `meta` root and then getting and setting any of its properties:

```
let meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')

console.log(meta.video.content)
> "http://video.com/video33353.mp4"

meta.video.content = "https://www.example.com/newlink"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with complex websites and metadata is that meta tags not always have the **itemprop** attribute. And in some case they have **itemprop** only but not a **name** attribute.

With this script you can get all the Meta with an itemprop attribute and print its content.

```
  const allMeta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    
  for (let i = 0; i < allMeta .length; i++) {
      if( allMeta [i].getAttribute("itemprop") != null){
        console.log( allMeta [i].getAttribute("itemprop")+":"+allMeta [i].getAttribute('content') );
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple with vanilla-js...

```
var author = document.querySelector("meta[name=author]").content;
alert(`My author is ${author}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="video" content="http://video.com/video33353.mp4" />
<meta name="video" content="http://video.com/video33353.mp4" />
</head>
<body>

<script>
var meta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    size = meta.length;

for(var i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (meta[i].getAttribute("property") === "video") {
        alert(meta[i].getAttribute("content"));
    }
}
meta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")["video"].getAttribute("content");
alert(meta);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bxtrguvn/)

Answer (score -2):

document.head.querySelector('meta[property=video]').content;

Comment: For Stackoverflow site purposes, your response needs to be more complete, with minimal explanation about your code.

Answer (score -3):

if the meta tag is:

```
<meta name="url" content="www.google.com" />
```

JQuery will be:

```
const url = $('meta[name="url"]').attr('content'); // url = 'www.google.com'
```

JavaScript will be: (It will return whole HTML)

```
const metaHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('meta').url // metaHtml = '<meta name="url" content="www.google.com" />'
```