# return content of meta tag to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the information from a meta tag with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)

I have a meta tag in which the content can be filled in on a customization page, and I need the content as a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3224334.htm has example code, see its discussion for more.

```
function getMetaContents(mn){
    var m = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for(var i in m){
        if(m[i][i].name == mn){
            return m[i].content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i don't think this will work for what i'm looking for. So the user specifies their twitter username in `<meta name = "text:Twitter Username" content=""/>` and i need their username as a variable. but i don't know what their username is. If i'm not mistaken the method above requires that the code is searching for content that equals 'mn'.

Comment: you can specify mn to be whatever you want.