# Javascript - Getting a page title and meta description and using them as variables for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script that gets the title from a tab and assigns it to a variable. However, I need to also get the `meta` `desc` and `title` properties for use in an `input` field.

I am not sure if I can achieve that with this:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {  
    var currentTitle = tab.title;  
});
```

Then I need to get the Meta description, which I don't believe I can get from the tab data.

This is the HTML I am getting the description from:

```
<meta name="description" content="contentstuffya" />
```

This is the Javascript I am using to get it outside of the extension:

```
document.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content');
```

How would I best do this given the data that I have?

Comment: what does that line of html containing `description` look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of a `<meta>` tag can only be read through a content script. Here's an example:

```js
var code = 'var meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=\'description\']");' + 
           'if (meta) meta = meta.getAttribute("content");' +
           '({' +
           '    title: document.title,' +
           '    description: meta || ""' +
           '});';
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: code
}, function(results) {
    if (!results) {
        // An error occurred at executing the script. You've probably not got
        // the permission to execute a content script for the current tab
        return;
    }
    var result = results[0];
    // Now, do something with result.title and result.description
});
```

At the first line, I locate the `<meta name="description">` element. At the second line, I read the value of its `content` attribute if the element is present.
The callback of [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) receives the last expression's return value, so I've put an object literal (wrapped in parentheses) at the end of the code.

Comment: Yes, I am a rookie. Maybe this is apparent from here but I am trying to return the title and meta to two input fields in my extension.

So the title would be the value of one input and the meta would be the value of another. How would I do that from this point? The executeScript makes all the js inside of it execute on the current tab rather than back at my extension.

Comment: @user2879869 So, you don't know how to continue at `// Now, do something with result.title and result.description`? What code do you have already? If you've got something like `<input id="title">`, then you can use `document.getElementById('title').value = result.title;`, for example. EDIT: The `code` in `executeScript` is executed in the context of the tab, but its callback runs in the original context, probably your extension's popup.

Comment: So replace `// Now, do something with result.title and result.description` with `document.getElementById('title').value = result.title;` ?

Comment: @user2879869 Yes, provided that you've got some HTML with ID `title`, i.e.. `<input type="text" id="title">`.

Comment: this is what I get now `Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined ` I appreciate the help, I am brand new to Javascript.

Comment: @user2879869 You probably removed `var result = ...;` by accident. Put it back, and follow the format of my answer.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. Do you happen to know how I can make it insensitive to case?

Comment: Make what case-insensitive? HTML attributes are already case-insensitive, `document.querySelector('MeTa[NaMe="DesCription"]')` does the same thing as the all-lowercase variant.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't grab it if its not lowercase. Beats me.

Comment: @user2879869 Probably a XHTML document. You can include multiple selectors, separated by commas: `'meta[name="description"],META[NAME="DESCRIPTION"]'` (and so on).

Comment: @RobW how to get the og:image

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is using this.

```
  function getMeta(metaName) {
   const metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

   for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    if (metas[i].getAttribute('name') === metaName) {
      return metas[i].getAttribute('content');
    }
   }

   return '';
  }

  console.log(getMeta('description'));
```

To get the title you can just use

```
console.log(document.title)
```

[How do I get the information from a meta tag with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)