# Passing Tokens in all request

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working on a project(without session,without cookies) in which whenever user hits any URL for the first time I redirect that page from my application to other login application and generate one token. on authentication success that token is passed back to the application and after that I redirect user to the page which he first requested. Now for all subsequent request user needs to carry that token so that application knows user is authenticated. Now my concern is

1)For the first time when Login application returns me with token how to add it to the Original request requested by the USER.

```
I)   I tried setting header with response.setHeader but not working 
II)  I cannot append it to URL
III) I cannot use sessions)
```

2)How to pass that token from one request to another when user hits any link.

Comment: The easiest, use cookies. If not you will have to add it as a parameter to all the URIs.

Comment: When you say `I tried setting header...` what do you mean that it did not work? Did your browser not get the header (it should have)?  If you were expecting the browser to automatically replay the header as a request parameter, that will certainly not happen. You have the choice to read the header value in the browser using JavaScript and then replay it with all future requests. This process works well, as evidenced by the fact that this same strategy is used by AJAX libraries such as EmberJS and AngularJS for replaying CSRF tokens (which are sent back by the server in HTTP headers).

Comment: @M.Deinum Cannot use cookies

Comment: @manish.in.java Can you give me a link of any docs for "Reading header value in javascript and then replay it with all future request"

Comment: Then you have a challenge, from the client you need to append the param/value to every GET URL (which exposes it to hackers which is insecure!) and encode it in the body of POST/PUT requests. You also need to find your own way of sending it back to the client (probably with a custom header). IMHO a cookie is more secure and less of a burden.

Comment: The easiest option is to include the value in an HTML Meta tag, such as `<meta property="X-AUTH-TOKEN" content="<secure, hard-to-replicate token>" />`.  Then, in JavaScript you can find this meta tag easily (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)).  As long as you exchange the meta tags over HTTPS, things should remain secure.  As M.Deinum said, to keep subsequent requests secure, you will have to add the token as a HTTP request header and use HTTPS.