# How to check for existing meta tag before generating a new one with javascript (or jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta-tags

I'm developing a widget that creates basic SEO tags that could already exist on a page so I'm wanting to make sure the widget checks for existing tags before the new tag is generated.

For example, one of the tags that the widget produces is

`<meta name="description" content="Description of the webpage"/>`

Since this tag is one that most pages already have, is there a way to use javascript to check for the tag before writing it?

Comment: I'm guessing its communicating to some database via server-side scripting?

Comment: @Jordumus, yes. I forgot to add that part.

Comment: You dont really need jQuery just for this. The performance is better with plain Javascript, given that we reduce the jQuery library loading time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Here is the plain Javascript solution (no libraries):*

Check for the meta description element using:
`document.querySelector("meta[name=description]");`

If found, access its `content` attribute using `.getAttribute("content")`.

**Demo:**

```js
if(document.querySelector("meta[name=description]")){

  if(document.querySelector("meta[name=description]").getAttribute("content") === "Description of the webpage")

    console.log("meta description with content 'Description of the webpage' found");
    // do something

}
else{

  console.log("meta description not found");
  // do something

}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Description of the webpage"/>
```

*Read up:*

- [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)
- [How do I get the information from a meta tag with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

Answer (score 2):

Sure its possible. Just use something like:

```
var description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/034ghy1y/

Comment: Perfect! I just wanted to add one more part that I found after using the code

`if ($('meta[name=description]').attr("content").is(':empty')){
  //do something
}`

Comment: Sure ;-). The description would be undefined if there is no meta description tag, so you could do if(description !== 'undefined') to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first meta tag found on a page.

```
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")
  if(tag[0]) {
    console.log('found ' + tag[0]);
  } else {
    console.log("Not found")
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gj9x5l8yS9xh2BoWkAm8?p=preview