# nightwatchjs meta tag check if is not empty

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I would like to check if the description meta tag has any value but not sure how to do it.

Have tried this but no luck:

```
browser.verify.element("meta[name=description]").attribute('content').not.equals('');
```

any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the [Selenium protocol "element"](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#element) :**

```
browser.element('css selector', '#advanced-search', function(result){
    if(result.status != -1){
        //Element exists, do something
    } else{
        //Element does not exist, do something else
    }
});
```

**Plain Javascript solution:**

```js
if(document.querySelector("meta[name=description]")){

  if(document.querySelector("meta[name=description]").getAttribute("content") === "Description of the webpage")

    console.log("meta description with content 'Description of the webpage' found");
    // do something

}
else{

  console.log("meta description not found");
  // do something

}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Description of the webpage"/>
```

Sources:  [Nightwatchjs: how to check if element exists without creating an error/failure/exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687027/nightwatchjs-how-to-check-if-element-exists-without-creating-an-error-failure-e) ,
[How to check for existing meta tag before generating a new one with javascript (or jquery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647336/how-to-check-for-existing-meta-tag-before-generating-a-new-one-with-javascript)

Comment: I did : this.verify.equal(1,2);  works but bad I believe.

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 I am not very familiar with nightwatch.js nor selenium but I think I pointed you in the right direction. You can check out the sources in in my answer and research further.