# How do I retrieve the content of meta property og in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, selector

I have the following in HTML code:

```
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Psychological Bulletin" />
```

It is quite easy to get the content by using:

```
document.getElementsByName("citation_journal_title")[0].getAttribute("content")
```

However, I cannot deal with this:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="APA PsycNET" />
```

How do you retrieve the content of `og:site_name`? 
I am aware of the question 
[How do I get the information from a meta tag with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)
 but I'm looking for something quite simple like

```
document.getElementsByName("citation_journal_title")[0].getAttribute("content")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use attribute selector [`[attr=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to do this work. Use it in `querySelector()` like this

```js
var attr = document.querySelector("meta[property='og:site_name']").getAttribute("content");
console.log(attr);
```

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="APA PsycNET" />
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In **Jquery**, you can use `attr()`

```
$('meta[property="og:site_name"]').attr('content')
```

In **JavaScript**, you can use `querySelector`

`querySelector` is supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

```
var element = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:site_name"]');
var content = element && element.getAttribute("content");
console.log(content);
```

**References**

- [How querySelector works?](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/finding_elements_dom_using_querySelector.htm)
- [w3schools article for querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)
- [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```js
console.log($('meta[property="og:site_name"]').attr('content'));

var element = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:site_name"]');
var content = element && element.getAttribute("content");
console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="APA PsycNET" />
```