# String Formatting | JavaScript | iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to extract the metadata description and keywords for a webpage using iMacros.

**The source code looks like this:**

```
<meta name="description" content="test test test">
<meta name="keywords" content="abc abc abc">
```

**The iMacros code looks like this:**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=META ATTR=NAME:"description" EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS=1 TYPE=META ATTR=NAME:"keywords" EXTRACT=HTM
```

**The Extract output from iMacros is :**

```
<meta name="description" content="test test test">
```

**Now, I just need the content part as my output :**

```
test test test
```

**I came to know that we can use JavaScript in iMacros using **EVAL** command. So, can one please help in formatting the string to desired output ?**

Comment: Why do you need to use the eval command? If the data is always the value of `content` attribute, you can use plain JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `EVAL` command. For example in this way:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=META ATTR=NAME:"description" EXTRACT=HTM
SET description EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/content="(.+?)"/)[1];")
PROMPT {{description}}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `content` attribute from the `<meta>` tag,
you can do this in plain JavaScript; there are good answers on this already:
[How do I get the information from a meta tag with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)

If you are using jQuery, it is easy to get the content of the meta tag you want using an expression like this:

```
var description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
```

Comment: I guess you misconstrued my question. The ouput variable is EXTRACT in which the meta string is stored. How do  I extract the content from EXTRACT ?

Comment: From your question I understood you want to do this in browser using JavaScript, i.e. extract it from the HTML (meta) tags