# How to group articles by meta article:tags in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm managing a web blog and each article has tags. I was wondering if I could see these tags in Google Analytics to see which tags are the most viewed.

The tags are present in the page, in the form of meta property, with multiple tags per page, for instance:

```
<meta property="article:tag" content="C++">
<meta property="article:tag" content="Performances">
```

Is there any way to get this information in Google Analytics ?

Most of my pages have several tags. I would need analytics on each tag individually, not on combinations of tags.

Edit: Here is what I tried:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'), tagsList = [];
  for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
    if (metas[i].getAttribute('property') == 'article:tag') {
      tagsList.push( metas[i].getAttribute('content'));
    }
  }
  ga('set', 'dimension1', tagsList.join('|'));
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

It's working if the script is AFTER the meta properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send the list of tags as a google analytics [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

This will let you see the tags associated to each page in the Google Analytics reports, together with the traffic metrics.

The drawback is that in the reporting, for a page having multiple tags, you will get the number of visits for this combination of tags, rather than the number of visits for each individual tag. You will need to download the report data in a spreadsheet, or perhaps in [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com), to cleanup and get the figures by tag.

### How to implement

#### 1. define the dimension in Google Analytics

The custom dimension should be set with at "hit level scope", this means that their values will be linked to the visited page(s).

Follow the [setup instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en#set_up_custom_dimensions).

#### 2. Send the tags list at page load

You should use javascript to lookup the meta tags, and send them to Google Analytics:

```
// read the set of tag values in javascript
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524621
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')
    , tagsList = []

for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) {
  if (metas[i].getAttribute('property') == 'article:tag') {
     tagsList.push( metas[i].getAttribute('content'))
  }
}

// set the list of tags as dimension value - as a comma-separated string
ga('set', 'dimension1', tagsList.join(','))

// then only send the pageview
ga('send', 'pageview')
```

#### 3. Profit!

In Google analytics reporting, the tags list can now be added to existing reports, or you may also create custom reports using them.

For example, try to add the tags list as a secondary dimension in `Behavior/Site Content / All Pages` report. Then click on "save" button at the top-right of the screen to re-use easily later.

The dimension will contain concatenated values of the tags, e.g. `C++,performances` rather than individual tags.

You may use either advanced filters or segments in order to get the metrics values per tag, e.g. the following filter will show you the metrics for the pages containing this tag:

```
dimension1 contains "C++"
```

If you want to go further and see all tag metrics in one report, use the `Export` feature to use the data in Excel, where you'll be able to split the tags list into individual tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand the drawback. If I have articles A1(tags: T1,T2) and A2 (tags: T2,T3), that means I cannot get the page views for any of the tags separately because they never appeared individually ? I only get pageviews for tuples (T1-T2) and (T2-T3). That is what you meant ?

Comment: yes, exactly. You would need to split the tuples by yourself, if you want the metrics per tag.

Comment: Oh, then  it's not really useful for me since almost all my articles have multiple categories. I was also thinking of using one custom dimension for each tag, but I would be limited to 20 which is not enough. Isn't there a way to better multi-tag tracking ?

Comment: I just edited the answer to add an example of how to see metrics for one tag, using "advanced filters" or "segments".

Comment: I'll try this and get back! Thanks

Comment: I tried your technique (I added my code in my post) but nothing is showing in GA after more than 12 hours. Any idea what is wrong ? The pageviews are still working, but the second dimension (Tags) does not show anything.

Comment: The function call to set the dimension should be done before `ga('send', 'pageview')`. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already doing this as you can see in the code I posted a few hours ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154430/discussion-between-mehdi-el-fadil-and-baptiste-wicht).