# How to write css selector for to get description from meta tag

Tags: css

from meta tag i want to write css selector for to get content from here meta[name='description']|content.May i know how to get that that content , when ever the name="description" then only i need to get the content from meta tag by using css selector meta[name='description']&content i wnat to get from css selector

```html
<meta name="description" content="efbfbfifckfuvhd">
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to get that content ? css doesn't return a value. With css you style elements.

Comment: It's not possible to return the content in CSS

Comment: You can try in javascript, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: I mean, the selectors for the elements in a DOM can be called "CSS selectors", because CSS is one of the  main reasons to use them. It's not accurate, but you know exactly what they mean, which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is not possible with CSS**
, Because CSS cannot return a content

But you can try it with Javascript like this:

```
document.querySelector("meta[name='description']").getAttribute("content");
```